# GAE Channel API message broadcast to only one client?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I'hv been trying to learn the Google App Engine's Channel API lately.

I tried to make a simple chat app, but I am reaching problems.

This is generally what i have done.

server opens a static channel:

```
token = channel.create_channel('bigboys')
```

client js connect to channel with:

```
var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token)
```

I am not using Google App Engines users. I don't want clients to have to login.

So my problem is, the chat app doesn't really work, only one client can join the channel. I know there is a one client ID per channel rule. So how do I support multiple clients in one "chat room"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of a channel being the connection between one client (browser) and your server.

If you have a chatroom, you'll need a channel for each client.  You'll need something on the server side to keep track of all the clients in the chatroom, and the channel for each client.  When you send a message, you'll need to send it on every client channel in the chatroom.

Comment: OKAY. that makes more sense then what I interpreted

Comment: So what is the optimal way to track all of the clients listening for the 'broadcast'?  Would you keep them in Memcache?  Datastore?

Comment: I'd have an entity in the datastore for the 'broadcast' which stores a list of all the clients.  Would use memcache to reduce hits to the datastore (ndb does this automatically).